# How to setup remote docker compose interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pycharm, interpreter

I would like to configure remote docker compose interpreter in PyCharm and I get following error:

[image]

```
Cannot create container for service jupyteo-hub: create \var\run\docker.sock: "\\var\\run\\docker.sock" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path
```

In docker-compose.yml file I bind /var/run/docker.sock as volume

```
# mount the docker socket
volumes:
  - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

Setup remote Docker interpreter finished without any problems and work fine but it is impossible to configure as a docker compose

I work with:

- PyCharm 2018.3.5 (Professional Edition) Build #PY-183.5912.18, built
  on February 26, 2019
- Windows 10 Home
- Docker Toolbox v 18.09.3
- VM - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and Python 3.6

All previous posts do not give positive solution. Any idea to solve this issue? Any workaround to get remote docker compose interpreter?

Comment: As you have the professional edition of Pycharm, I would open a ticket at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/?pycharm

Comment: It will be great. I use latest version of professional edition of PyCharm. Regarding this issue I suppose problem is with Docker Compose path. In PyCharm it is possible to set only local path to Docker Compose and it point to Windows. All other elements of this configuration point to remote resources. On this point PyCharm mix Windows and Linux enviroments what results this kind of error (typical for running Linux code in Windows).